# Reading application.properties in static method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the below code when i put some properties statically in `SpringApplicationBuilder`

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com" })
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplicationBuilder parentBuilder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class);
        parentBuilder.child(RestConfiguration.class, SwaggerConfig.class)
                .properties("server.port:9093")).web(WebApplicationType.SERVLET).run(args);
    }
}
```

I want to move the properties to the file `application.properties`

```
application.port.query=9093
```

I used `@value` to read from the application file, but i get null. Is there another way to read data in a static method?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("application")
class A {
     public static int queryPort;
     @Value("${port.query:9093}")
     public void setQueryPort(final int portQuery){
         A.queryPort = portQuery;
     }
 }

public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplicationBuilder parentBuilder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class);
    parentBuilder.child(RestConfiguration.class, SwaggerConfig.class)
    .properties(A.queryPort)).web(WebApplicationType.SERVLET).run(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The preferable way to what you are trying to achieve is to use the spring bean itself which is the parent of your all configurations [org.springframework.core.env.Environment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html)

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext =
                SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        Environment environment = applicationContext.getBean(Environment.class);
        String propertyValue = environment.getProperty("any.property.from.configuration")
    }
}
```

In your use-case, just get the bean of `Environment` and from `Environment` object get any property value.